# How to Call and Run a Class within a Unit test? c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Currently playing around with some automation stuff. And had a question - I've only just started doing this and wanted to understand how this works and why I can't get it to work.

Unit Test:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testenv
{
    class LoginTest
    {
        IWebDriver driver;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void startBrowser()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void test()
        {
            driver.Url = "http://www.google.com";
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void closeBrowser()
        {
            driver.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Want I want to do is create a common class - that contains some of these methods and call them within multiple tests.

So I would want to create a Class like:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testenv
{
    class LoginClass
    {

        public void test()
        {
            driver.Url = "http://www.google.com";
        }

    }
}
```

How do I go about calling this Class Method in the unit test as it makes a lot of sense to just keep calling the method, especially over multiple tests?

Comment: You can use [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance). As for calling the method again and again, that can be dangerous, making tests brittle. For example, imagine a test runner that runs your tests simultaneously.

Comment: I think you misunderstand of unit testing purposes. Unit test testing **existing** methods of **existing** classes. You dont need to generate new classes within tests. You must test existing _"production"_ classes

Comment: @DavidG I read the question so that OP wants to get rid of boilerplate code. Not to use one shared instance of something ... (am I right, themightykai?)

Comment: @Fildor Could be, I did kinda skim read it :)

Comment: @DavidG I actually want to make it boiler plate in this repect so that for any tests in future I can just call that class / method :)

Comment: So my comment is still relevant, yay.

Comment: @DavidG is there a better way to handle this then?

It would also still be nice to know how to do it xD lol. I'm just playing around atm. This isn't really for unit tests btw - it's actually to build a small automated pack for a site.